# Opengles shaders interpolation issue

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I see problems related to accuracy of interpolation by shaders. I get a distorted blue line as shown below due to accuracy of interpolation of varying variable (height in this case) by shaders. How do I fix it?

[image]

Here is how I feed the data to shaders:

```
    uint8_t * oglData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(_pixelBuffer);  

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 256; i++) {

       /* Only first two columns blue in BGRA 256x1 buffer */     
        if (i < 2) {
            oglData[4 * i] =   255;
            oglData[4 * i + 1] =  0;
            oglData[4 * i +2]   = 0;
            oglData[4 * i +3] = 1;
        } else {
            oglData[4 * i] =   0;
            oglData[4 * i + 1] =  0;
            oglData[4 * i +2]   = 0;
            oglData[4 * i +3] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And here are shaders:

Vertex shader:

```
   attribute vec4 position;
   attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;

   varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
   varying float height;

   void main()
   {
     gl_Position = position;                                                          
     textureCoordinate = vec2(inputTextureCoordinate.x, 0.0);
     height = inputTextureCoordinate.y;
   }
```

Fragment Shader:

```
   varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
   varying highp float height;

   uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
   uniform lowp vec4 backgroundColor;

   void main() {
     lowp vec3 colorChannels = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate).rgb;
                                                               //  
    if (colorChannels.b >= height) {                
                 gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    } else {                                                      
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);                                                  
    }

  }
```

Here is the drawing code:

```
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 256, 1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, oglData);

glUniform1i( _inputImageTexture, 0 );

// Set texture parameters
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

glVertexAttribPointer( ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( ATTRIB_VERTEX );

glVertexAttribPointer( ATTRIB_TEXTURECOORDINATE, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureCoordinates );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( ATTRIB_TEXTURECOORDINATE );

glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4 );

glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorBufferHandle );
[_oglContext presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

EDIT: Changing GL_LINEAR to GL_NEAREST fixes the issue, which means varying vars are interpolated based on the type of min & mag filters in texture parameters? But using GL_Nearest creates non-smooth curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I fix it?

You can't (at least not directly) - this is fixed function hardware inside the GPU, so you'll just have to live with it.

> Changing GL_LINEAR to GL_NEAREST fixes the issue, which means varying vars are interpolated based on the type of min & mag filters in texture parameters?

No - varying interpolation has nothing to do with the texture min/mag filters.

Your issue is that the inaccuracy in the varying interpolation is causing the sample point input into your `texture()` function call to drift away from the texel center, so the `GL_LINEAR` texture filtering starts to have an effect.
By using `GL_NEAREST` you effectively quantize the sampling points, so as long as the error is less than half a texel wide you snap back to the texel you want.

Comment: So you say that varying interpolation's accuracy is the culprit and it's shockingly impossible to draw a vertical line in one color?

Comment: Should be possible - `highp` is fp32 so gives you 23 fractional bits so should be able to address this accurately. Without a complete reproducer it's going to be hard to determine exactly what's going wrong though. How big is your screen, and what texture coordinates are you passing it at the corners?